# Elif Statements are Being Ignored

Tags: python

I am coding brick breaker and my third and fourth elif conditions are being ignored.

In order to differentiate between a hit to the side of a brick horizontally or laterally to correspondingly alter the direction of the ball, I specified a 5-pixel margin that is continuously checked. My code correctly determines when the ball lands in the top or bottom margin but the ball simply passes through the sides even though I wrote those conditions in the same way. I know that the statements are being ignored completely because all of the functions of the statement are ignored.

the border markers within the bricks to specify the margins have a B at the end

```
def collision(self):
    if (ball.xcor() > self.colisL) and (ball.xcor() < self.colisR) and (ball.ycor() > self.colisD) and (ball.ycor() < self.colisDB):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        ball.dy *= -1
        self.colisU = 1000
        self.colisD = 1000
        self.colisL = 1000
        self.colisR = 1000
        global score
        score += 1
    elif (ball.xcor() > self.colisL) and (ball.xcor() < self.colisR) and (ball.ycor() < self.colisU) and (ball.ycor() > self.colisUB):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        ball.dy *= -1
        self.colisU = 1000
        self.colisD = 1000
        self.colisL = 1000
        self.colisR = 1000
        score += 1
    elif (ball.xcor() > self.colisL) and (ball.xcor() < self.colisLB) and (ball.ycor() > self.colisD) and (ball.ycor() < self.colisU):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        ball.dx *= -1
        self.colisU = 1000
        self.colisD = 1000
        self.colisL = 1000
        self.colisR = 1000
        score += 1
    elif (ball.xcor() > self.colisR) and (ball.xcor() < self.colisRB) and (ball.ycor() > self.colisU) and (ball.ycor() < self.colisU):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        ball.dx *= -1
        self.colisU = 1000
        self.colisD = 1000
        self.colisL = 1000
        self.colisR = 1000
        score += 1
```

Comment: I'm fairly confident the statements are not being ignored since the statements are syntactically correct. Most likely you are not meeting the conditions to enter either of the statements. I would suggest you provide some sample values, otherwise this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax of if...elif...else**

```
if test expression:
    Body of if
elif test expression:
    Body of elif
else: 
    Body of else
```